# Форматирование диска в NTFS

Tags: linux, файловая-система

Здравствуйте, с Linux Mint форматнул диск на 1tb, в какую-то файловую систему, уже не помню, но там было предупреждение о том, что с виндой может работать не корректно. Через неделю после этого поставил винду, и она не видит этот диск, перепробовал море способов, понял, что винда просто не хочет его видеть. Вопрос:
Как с линукса форматнуть диск в NTFS?

Comment: Через Gparted...

Comment: Я думаю запуск *mkfs.ntfs* с правильными опциями всё сделает.

Comment: @VladSpirin, gparted научился структуры ФС создавать?

Comment: @0andriy вопрос был про форматирование, если форматировать, то он подходит.